# Como ejecutar un texto como una funcion python3

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo las siguientes entradas:

```
#borrar varios elementos de una lista - solo es un ejemplo de una función tonta y sin importancia
def borrar_elemento(lista, posiciones):
     for posicion in posiciones:
          lista.pop(posicion)

lista = ["platano","manzana","pera","sandía","guayaba"]
funcion = "borrar_elemento"
posiciones = [1,2]
```

Deseo ejecutar el texto como una función y pasarle por parámetro los ids. Por ejemplo algo como esto:

```
funcion(lista,posiciones)
```

El problema es que no funciona asi la cosa ya que da el siguiente error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. Dado a que no ejecuta un texto como una función. Pensé en alguna especie de casteo pero ahí me quede. Tengan en cuenta que la función a la que quiero acceder esta importada o escrita en el mismo archivo .py .

Comment: Investiga sobre la función `eval`...

Comment: Voy a quitar la etiqueta django, ya que, si bien quiza tu objetivo es aplicar esto en django, la pregunta en si no tiene que ver con dicho.

Comment: ¿Por qué deseas ejecutar una función por su nombre textual? Probablemente hay mejores formas de solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mejor camino que se me ocurre es el siguiente:

```
class funciones:
    def hola_mundo_printer(msg):
        print("hola mundo", msg)

getattr(funciones, "hola_mundo_printer")("msg1", "msg2")
```

El plan es crear una clase funciones y dentro de esta la funcion a la que queremos acceder usando una cadena. Mas tarde, creada la clase, usamos la función `getattr(objeto, atributo en forma de cadena, valor default)` para acceder a la funcion usando una cadena (esta funcion esta almacenada como atributo de clase). Teniendo la función, solo hace falta llamarla con los argumentos deseados.

Esta es la forma que siempre uso para satisfacer esta necesidad y, ademas, es usada en el modulo ast.

**Ventajas de este sistema sobre acceder a una funcion con eval o diccionarios de variables**

- Es sintacticamente mas agradable de ver.
- Es mas seguro, pues las funciones están en un "entorno" separado. Por lo que no pones en jaque a las variables de uso interno.
- (Solo aplica a eval) es mas seguro, por que no es posible una inyeccion de código (es decir, código malicioso ingresado por el usuario).

Nota 1: si la funcion deseada es ingresada por el usuario, para evitar que se ejecute una funcion que no quieres que el usuario ejecute, podes usar un prefijo. Algo como *user_* hola_mundo_printer. Y usar `getattr(clase, f"user_{nombre_funcion}"`.

Nota 2: existen formas de lograr lo mismo sin usar clases, pero es necesario el uso de eval (que podria servir para que suceda una inyeccion de código) o acceder a las variables locales con locals(), lo cual no es nada agradable. Si lo quieres ver de todas formas, dimelo en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llamar a la función por nombre de forma dinámica obteniendo su puntero en el ámbito (scope) local:

```py
import sys
getattr(sys.modules[__name__], funcion)(lista, posiciones)
```

Aquí una explicación:

- `a = sys.modules`: contiene todos los módulos en "importables"
- `b = a[__name__]` es el scope de tu propio código
- `c = getattr(b, funcion)` obtiene llamable a tu función.
- `c(lista, posiciones)` llama a la función.

Comment: No es necesario importar un modulo adicional. Podes acceder a las variables locales o globales del script que se ejecuta actualmente usando locals y globals. Sin embargo, yo no lo considero una forma muy limpia.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes que ejecutar una función dado su nombre, es obvio que la debes tener definida en tu programa. Por tanto, tienes nombre y código.

Crea un diccionario de funciones:

```
def funcion_uno(a, b, c):
    pass

def funcion_dos(a, b, c):
    pass


funciones = {
   "funcion_uno": funcion_uno,
   "funcion_dos": funcion_dos
   }
```

Luego, cuando te den un nombre de función, la puedes ejecutar con

```
funciones[nombre_funcion](a, b, c)
```

Ventaja adicional: puedes tener diccionarios con implementaciones alternativas de las mismas funciones (por ejemplo, una para usuarios comunes y otra para privilegiados). Con solo cambiar de diccionario la misma aplicación funciona para ambos casos.